# 2 buttons in front page, each button get different function to another page

Tags: java, android-studio, code-generation, qr-code

I was watching and tried to do the tutorial for the generator QR Code in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e5pI6CSxAX8).

And then like in the end of it when he want to try the generator works, he shows some kind a 2 buttons, 1 for the scanner and 1 for the generator.

But in the video he didn't explain how he do it. I already tried his video about the scanner but still no clue. Can someone help me?

UPDATE:
Now here's my new problem regarding with gradle version:

Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.10.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Users/User/Downloads/android-studio-ide-171.4443003-windows32/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.10/gradle-2.10.pom
    file:/C:/Users/User/Downloads/android-studio-ide-171.4443003-windows32/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.10/gradle-2.10.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.10/gradle-2.10.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.10/gradle-2.10.jar
    https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.10/gradle-2.10.pom
    https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.10/gradle-2.10.jar
Required by:
    :QRCode:unspecified
Open File

Anybody can help me fix this?

Comment: Show some code, or atleast share the video at the current time where you got the problem.

Comment: It showns at 15:40, where there's a  2 buttons but he never shows how its done

Comment: can someone help me please?

Comment: @VISWESWARANNAGASIVAM Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the description of the Youtube video, there is a link to the source code

https://github.com/prudhvirajkumar10/QR-Code/

download the source code and open MainActivity.java

@Line 10 in MainActivity.java he declared the two buttons like this,

```
Button gen, scan; // gen for generate and scan for scanning qr code
```

Again in MainActivity.java you can see this code,

```
gen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent gIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GeneratorActivity.class);
                startActivity(gIntent);
            }
        });
```

The above "OnClickListener" gets executed when the gen button is pressed. When "GENERATE" button is pressed it moves from MainActivity to the GeneratorActivity which you can find in "GeneratorActivity.java"

Similar thing happens when clicking scan button, Look at these code in MainActivity.java

```
scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent rIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReaderActivity.class);
                startActivity(rIntent);
            }
        });
```

When "SCAN" button is clicked it changes from MainActivity to ReaderActivity which is found in "ReaderActivity.java".

If you have any doubt feel free to ask me.

Comment: Thank you sir for helping me, I got some issues with the code that I just donwload from github. My gradle is not compatible with the code, it said could not find my gradle. How to fix this sir? And can you help me with another question that I post about the scanner please?

Comment: By the way, I just install the apk from the github code but there's no respond from it